# Implementing backpropagation in Theano

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation, theano

I have been playing around with Theano for a while and read a lot of code examples and it looks like every time Theano graph needs to find gradients for a list of parameters it uses T.grad() function. Reading up on the grad() implementation, it seems that it is not doing backpropagation, but rather relies on chain rule and individual ops knowing how to differentiate themselves.

Am I correct? How are the results different using this two methods? Does it make sense to implement backpropagation in Theano?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct that automatic differentiation (including theano's `grad` function) just uses the chain rule. The interesting point is that this is also how backpropagation works; it's just the chain rule. The standard backprop equations for computing the weight update direction amount to computing the gradient of the loss function with respect to the parameters.

The traditional way of training a network with backprop looks like this:

1. Forward pass. Compute the activations and loss function, given the inputs and parameters. These will be used for computing the gradient in the next step.
2. Backward pass. Compute the gradient of the loss function with respect to the parameters.
3. Update parameters by moving in the direction opposite the gradient, with some step size.

So, traditional backprop training is just gradient descent. When you compute the gradient with theano, the result will be identical to what you'd get with the forward and backward passes using the backprop equations. Under the hood, theano is using reverse-mode automatic differentiation which, in the case of neural nets, is equivalent to the backprop equations (perhaps modulo some optimizations of the computational graph that theano might make to increase efficiency).

To complete the backprop training implementation, you'd just have to add some code for updating the parameters, given the gradient. Of course, there are many fancier modifications of the traditional gradient descent update rule, which you could use to boost performance.

Comment: Eh... my understanding is that backpropagation is not gradient descent. Backpropagation is an algorithm for calculating gradients of parameters by loss function. Gradient descent is an optimization algorithm for training that uses backpropagation to calculate the gradients. There are many optimizations for gradient descent, like SGD, momentum, adagrade etc. But backprop is still the main algorithm for calculating gradients. There are versions of it adapted for different types of models (like BPTT for RNNs), but under the hood it is still the same basic algorithm.

Comment: Yes, and if you use theano's autodiff on the `scan` function it can can perform BPTT. I didn't imply that backprop = gradient descent. I worded things carefully to distinguish between computing the gradient via backprop proper, and the larger context of a backprop-based training procedure (including the weight update, which may or may not be vanilla gradient descent). Perhaps the wording was too subtle, maybe I'll edit later.

Comment: Thank you. So, the answer I am getting out of this is that grad() function in Theano essentially does the same thing as backprop algorithm plus maybe some optimization stemming from knowing the graph structure. I think that answers my question, thank you for the insight.

Comment: Yep. `grad` can give the gradient for any computational graph whose nodes are differentiable, so it's more general. But, it does the same thing as backprop when applied to neural nets.